# Trouble understanding blocks and yields in ruby

Tags: ruby, block, yield, monkeypatching

I'm a beginner in ruby and going through a tutorial which deals with blocks and yields, and particularly demonstrating Monkey Patching.

Here is the requirement of the code challenge

> Write a new new_map method that is called on an instance of the Array class. It should use >the array it's called on as an implicit (self) argument, but otherwise behave identically.

Here is the code I have submitted

```
class Array

  def new_map(&block)
    self.map(&block)
  end

  def new_select!(&block)
    self.replace(self.select(&block))
  end

end
```

Here are the Specs I have to pass

```
describe Array do
  describe '#new_map' do
    it "returns an array with updated values" do
     array = [1,2,3,4]
     expect( array.new_map(&:to_s) ).to eq( %w{1 2 3 4} )
     expect( array.new_map{ |e| e + 2 } ).to eq( [3, 4, 5, 6] )
    end

    it "does not call #map" do
     array = [1,2,3,4]
     array.stub(:map) { '' }
     expect( array.new_map(&:to_s) ).to eq( %w{1 2 3 4} )
    end

    it "does not change the original array" do
      array = [1,2,3,4]
      expect( array.new_map(&:to_s) ).to eq( %w{1 2 3 4} )
      expect( array ).to eq([1,2,3,4])
    end
end
```

I passed the first and last test but could not pass the second one and received this error

```
expected: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
     got: ""

(compared using ==)

exercise_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

From the specs, am I to assume that the `.map` method was not supposed to be used in this particular challenge?

I even tried this with that assumption. But it did not pass any of the specs.

```
def new_map(array)
  new_array =[]
  array.each do |i|
    new_array << yield(i)
  end
  new_array
end
```

**Update**

I entered this code and it worked

```
def new_map
  new_array = []
  self.each do |i|
    new_array << yield(i)
  end
  new_array
end
```

But I was hoping someone could help me understand why I had to remove the argument `(array)` and hence change `array.each` to `self.each`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I was hoping someone could help me understand why I had to remove the argument (array) and hence change array.each to self.each?

1. **Background**: Your first method was looking for an argument that doesn't actually need to be passed as array is the caller itself; in other words you are trying to pass the caller (or `self`) as argument to the method. Technically you can do that, but thats not required.
2. **Reason for failure**: But if you had got an error running the specs with the previous definition thats because the method definition was changed by adding that argument. That is, you *have to* call method 1 like this:

   new_map array { block }

While the argument array is actually not being passed, hence giving you an `ArgumentError`.

Answer (score 0):

The new_map is an instance method of the Array class making your array == self

```
[1,2,3].new_map(&:to_s)
```

the self is the [1,2,3] which is your Array instance

```
self.each do |i|
```

is like

```
[1,2,3].each do |i|
```

then each of 1,2 and 3 would be passed to the block

```
new_array << yield(i)
```

Comment: Thank you, in essence, since the new_map method is an instance of the Array class, passing in an argument as (array) becomes redundant?

Comment: yes indeed. And looking through the specs that you have to pass you only need to pass a block.